# Can the Potion of Life be muled to provide a character with a steady stream of +20 to life?

Tags: diablo-ii

If I have a main character who as completed all 3 difficulty levels and received +60 life from the 3 Golden Bird quests and I have another character who has completed the same quest on normal, can the potion of life the lesser character receives be muled to the main character (for a total of +80 life) or does some game mechanic prevent this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question could also be extended to include other quest items that provide a permanent bonus, such as the Book of Skill. In any case, a single character cannot pick up (or get by trade) a quest item more than once per difficulty, so the answer is that your proposed scheme will not work.

Otherwise, it would be possible to continually create new characters just for these quest items and then buff up a single character for unbounded skill points and HP.

Comment: Ok, an extension to that question: Is there a risk of breaking the game if I use external program to mule the item? I only play single player and use a program to store my items in files instead of creating more characters.

Comment: @TomášZato Dunno. But usually save-game editors and other similar programs allow you to just directly modify your HP anyway.... In any case, you might get a better answer if you ask this as a new, separate, question.